# Internal data leak withing DataBuffer JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, google-geocoder

Im doing some work from an android app im making, i want the app to add data to my mysql database using json and POST.

Logcat:

```
11-15 17:29:44.928: E/DataHolder(1059): Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call close() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@41edce60)
11-15 17:29:44.938: E/DataHolder(1059): Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call close() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@41ee92e8)
11-15 17:29:44.938: E/DataHolder(1059): Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call close() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@41edc4e8)
11-15 17:29:44.948: E/DataHolder(1059): Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call close() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@41e6f988)
11-15 17:29:44.958: E/DataHolder(1059): Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call close() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@41e663d0)
11-15 17:29:44.958: E/DataHolder(1059): Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call close() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@41ec8308)
11-15 17:29:44.958: E/DataHolder(1059): Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call close() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@41ea75e0)
11-15 17:29:44.978: E/DataHolder(1059): Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call close() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@41e8a590)
11-15 17:29:44.978: E/DataHolder(1059): Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call close() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@41e6b478)
11-15 17:29:44.988: E/DataHolder(1059): Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call close() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@41f0d378)
11-15 17:29:44.998: E/DataHolder(1059): Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call close() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@41f14648)
```

My Activity:

```
public class AddLocationActivity extends Activity {

    EditText edClubName, edAddress, edAge, edDescription;
    String sClubName, sAddress, sAge, sDescription;
    double lat, lng;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static String url_create_product = "http://000100023.host56.com/db_create.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_location);

        ActionBar abs = getActionBar();
        abs.setTitle(R.string.activity_title_add_location);
        abs.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddLocationActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            edClubName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edClubName);
            edAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edAddress);
            edAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edAge);
            edDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDescription);

            sClubName = edClubName.getText().toString();
            sAddress = edAddress.getText().toString();
            sAge = edAge.getText().toString();
            sDescription = edDescription.getText().toString();

            try {
                addLocation(edAddress);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            String sLat = String.valueOf(lat);
            String sLng = String.valueOf(lng);

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", sClubName));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", sAddress));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", sDescription));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", sAge));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", sLat));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", sLng));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Done");

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Failed");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    public void addLocation (View v) throws IOException {       

        Geocoder mGc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> mList = mGc.getFromLocationName(sAddress, 1);
        Address mAddress = mList.get(0);

        String locality = mAddress.getLocality();

        lat = mAddress.getLatitude();
        lng = mAddress.getLongitude();

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Lat: " + lat + " Lng: " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void cancelAddLocation () {

    }
}
```

I want the user to add the data, it uses Geocode to get the lat and long of the location, then add it to the database using an php script:

Php script:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['age']) && isset($_POST['rating']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lng'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $rating = $_POST['age'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $lng = $_POST['lng'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once 'db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO view(id, name, age, rating, info, hours, dresscode, location, tribe, lat, lng, verified) VALUES('', '$name', '$age', '$rating', '$description', '', '', '$location', '', '$lat', '$lng', '0')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT:
When trying the answere, i get this error:

```
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795): Process: com.spxc.nightclubratings, PID: 8795
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3814)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     ... 11 more
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: locationName == null
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:171)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     at com.spxc.nightclubratings.AddLocationActivity.addLocation(AddLocationActivity.java:151)
11-15 17:48:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8795):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: this issue could be in `makeHttpRequest`

Comment: what could the problem be?

Comment: @stianInstebo can you comment the `try {
                addLocation(edAddress);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }` and give fake values to `slat` & `slan` and check if the app is working?!

Comment: hard to tell without the actual code, but it looks like something is opening DataBuffers, and I don't see any of this in your code.

Comment: your log cat says `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: locationName == null` the error is at line 171, what is this line?

Comment: i dont have a line 171, last is 167

Comment: you arent running the `AsynTask` add `new CreateNewProduct().execute();` in `onCreate()` but i dont think you this will solve the problem. please give me feedback after you add the line

Comment: That wont work, because it has to get values from the edittext boxes, and the line 171 is: List<Address> mList = mGc.getFromLocationName(sAddress, 1); changed sAddress to = "", no FC, nothing, wont even add row to DB

Comment: even if the user has filled the edittexts , the app wont launch the asynctask without adding the previous code, unless that wasnt your all the code within the activity. what you can do is after the user fill the edittext. add a button and in onclick() call the `asynctask`.

Comment: That is all the code tho

Comment: Got it working, added new CreateNewProduct().execute(); to the click :) thanks guys! :)

Comment: The only thing i need to figure out now is how to get Lat and Lng into the parameters...

Comment: it worked with or without commenting the `addLocation(edAddress);` and if you saw my below answer is right i hope u rate it or mark it as right

Comment: I got it working, i did something wierd in my code :P time too get some sleep i guess. And your answere was right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant define any UI object within `doInBackground()` like these codes:

```
edClubName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edClubName);
edAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edAddress);
edAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edAge);
edDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDescription);
```

however, you can add them in `onPreExecute()`

so do this:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddLocationActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

        edClubName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edClubName);
        edAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edAddress);
        edAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edAge);
        edDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDescription);
    }

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String sClubName = edClubName.getText().toString();
        String sAddress = edAddress.getText().toString();
        String sAge = edAge.getText().toString();
        String sDescription = edDescription.getText().toString();

        //complete with the code
```

Comment: i'm not so sure of that. there is no modification made to the element, so the access should not be thread-checked.

Comment: I just try to add an `edittext` to my web app and it got crash same error, adding UI to doInBackground cause leak.. the second error caused by calling addLocation(..) but i still cant figure out why? i have never used geoCoder within `AsyncTask`